# Text after space cut off in input form html / php

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm sure this is just something daft but im going crazy trying to resolve it

Basically im using the below to select a file from my computer and then use a text field to allow any text to be inputted to watermark the gif, this all works fine for say "stackoverflow.com" but as soon as any spaces are added example "My Watermark" only the My bit gets watermarked

Obviously the code below is stripped down but should be enough

```
<form method="post" name="form" enctype="multipart/form-data"><fieldset>
<strong>Image (max size 11MB):</strong><input name="image" type="file" /><br />
<strong>Watermark Text:</strong><input name="watermarktext" type="text" value="watermark my gif" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Top watermark" class="submit" onclick="javascript: form.action='top.php';" />         
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Bottom watermark" class="submit" onclick="javascript: form.action='bottom.php';" />


$watermarktext = ($_POST["watermarktext"]);

exec("MAGICK_THREAD_LIMIT=1 convert " . $store . $id . "original.gif --coalesce -gravity South -background white -splice 0x18 -annotate 0 " . $watermarktext . " -layers Optimize "
```

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Basically it is being passes as separate arguments. You need to wrap it in quote as follows:

```
exec("MAGICK_THREAD_LIMIT=1 convert " . $store . $id . "original.gif --coalesce -gravity South -background white -splice 0x18 -annotate 0 \"" . $watermarktext . "\" -layers Optimize "
```